# How can the numbercolumn in EXTjs 3.4 grid to display indian number format?

Tags: extjs

How can the numbercolumn in EXTJS 3.4 grid be formatted to display indian number format?

Eg: 45,78,895.45

Comment: Can you please create a fiddle. So I can help you better. When I checked Sencha docs at :- https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/modern/Ext.grid.column.Number.html
It says that this thing does have a renderer!

Comment: I am working on a much older version of extjs, 3.4.0, which does not support numbercolumn renderer updation.

Answer (score 0):

One way you can do it is not ideal but you can override the `Ext.grid.RowNumberer` and tweak you rowNumber using javascript so that it returns in Indian number style. To do that we will use `myNumString.toLocaleString('en-In');` method. I have created the function already for you. Here is the [Example(fiddle)](https://jsfiddle.net/3egztdL9/10/). please mark this as answered if this solved your problem so that others can benefit from it. If something doesn't look right then please comment. Please look at the function below:

```
Ext.override(Ext.grid.RowNumberer, {
    renderer: function(value, metaData, record, rowIdx, colIdx, store) {
      var rowspan = this.rowspan;
      if (rowspan) {
        metaData.tdAttr = 'rowspan="' + rowspan + '"';
      }
      metaData.tdCls = Ext.baseCSSPrefix + 'grid-cell-special';
      //return store.indexOfTotal(record) + 1;
      var incrementedRowId = rowIdx + 1; //doing +1 as row id starts from 0
      var indianRowNumber = incrementedRowId.toLocaleString('en-In');
      return indianRowNumber;
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by using the `renderer` function. This way your store value woldn't have ',' but your grid appearance will. First things first ext stores numbercolumn as a string so we will use `parseInt` function to convert it to int and then we will use `myNum.toLocaleString('en-In')` this function will help us convert the number to Indian number string. Take a look at this [example(fiddle)](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2jqb) for better explanation. So basically whichever grid column value you want to show as Indian number just add the following function while declaring the grid column:

```
`header: "Indian Number Column",
 dataIndex: 'currency',
 flex: .5,
 sortable: true,
 renderer: function (val, metaData, r){
     return parseInt(val).toLocaleString('en-In');
 }`
```

> Things you need to make sure are:
>
> Don't forget to use parseInt or parseFloat as toLocaleString only works on numbers and ext stores numbercolumn value as a string
>
> The value of the column is always a number so the parseInt doesnt fail

Bonus hint: 
If you are dealing with currency and you want to add the Indian currency symbol and also want to round the decimal value then use the following code instead:

```
`header: "Indian Number Column",
 dataIndex: 'currency',
 flex: .5,
 sortable: true,
 renderer: function (val, metaData, r){
     return parseFloat(val).toLocaleString('en-In', {
         maximumFractionDigits: 2,
         style: 'currency',
         currency: 'INR'
         });
      }`
```

Comment: for the number column, the renderer is assigned by the constructor itself. It cannot be overridden even if it is assigned with a new renderer in the config. Finally I extend the class column and add myown renderer in that, and that works.

Comment: That is called a rownumberer not a number column. I had made a solution for that but then I deleted it. Lemme check if I can undelete it. Or ill post it in 12 hrs

Comment: rownumberer is another feature, I know that.

Comment: Is it fine if u use rownumberer instead of what you are using? Coz I have already made a solution for that!

Comment: Look at the other answer I just undeleted

Comment: Thanks for your time and effort, Retnani.

Comment: @Monsy you're wlcome. Please answer this question! Can u use rownumberer instead?

Comment: No, I can't use the rownumberer. It is a different feature.

Comment: @Monsy I would still suggest you to check the other answer and override the numbercolumn the same way I am overriding the rownumberer

Comment: That will not work for numbercolumn, as the constructor is updating the renderer to default Number Renderer after calling the super class constructor with current config.

Comment: Please post some of you code and a fiddle so I can help you better. Anytime you post a question please try to include code and snippet or fiddle if possible. That would save your question from getting downvoted.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the better way is to write your own locale file for India (that's if they don't supply their own, though I can't see one). Have a look for the locale folder in your Ext framework download and copy the style of the file.